# How make skip to next "else" o "end" in a interpreter written in C#

Tags: c#, interpreter

I've written an interpreter for my personal language (almost) and i've implemented `cin, cout, variable` declaration and others.

Now I'm stuck on implement `if` statement, first of all `nested if` statement.

I can't get the end of an `if` statement block when there are multiple `nested if`
because it stop before get the real end of the block due to end of other block

**Example:**

```
if var is 7 <- at every if my method start

if var is greater than 6

if var is less than 8

write no

else

write yes

end

else <- my method get this line but

write ok

end

else <- it should give me this line

write no

end
```

**here is my code, i've try different one and this is the better**

String[] Control = Global.Code; //here is the source code 
        bool isAlone = false;

```
    int ok = 0; // variable to return (line of the else or end)

    for (int i = riga + 1; i < Control.Length; i++)
    {
        restart:
        if (Control[i].Contains("if"))
        {

            isAlone = true;
        }



        if (Control[i] == "end" && isAlone == true)
        {
            isAlone = false;
            i += 1;
            goto restart;

        }

        if(Control[i] == "end" || Control[i] == "else" && isAlone == false )
        {
            ok = i;
            break;
        }

    }

    return ok;
}
```

Comment: You'd have to use a stack, or treat it recursively, actually you have to follow your grammar, as long as it is LL(1) you just translate it into function calls.

Comment: how i have to use stack? what do you mean for "treat it recursively" ?

Comment: Stack : you see an if, you push it in the stack, you see an end, you pull its if from the stack (there you'll always much the if with its end, and if you find an end and nothing is in your stack, or the program ends with a non-empty stack you can detect there a syntax error.  Recursively (thus using an implicit stack) , is simply building your decoding program based on your grammar, so you'll have a "decode_if" which will call itself when it finds an if and exits when it sees the "end".

Comment: thanks for the advice!, another question: how i can find else if the stack contain only if and end?

Comment: Easiest is : you see an else, you pull the if, you push the else , and the "end" pulls an if or an else (thus closing the structure), if the stack is empty at the else => syntax error.